# Why is Processing.js giving me an error about a function that isn't in my code?

Tags: javascript, processing, typography, processing.js

So I'm using processing.js to make some abstract looking typography (such as [this](http://dullneon.com/randomnotes/images-videos-and-other-content/2016/07/scriptographer.gif)), and I found someone's code that I would like to use as a base for my own code.  I tried copying and pasting it into open processing, the online editor for processing, and it gives me this error when I try to run it: `drawing.$ensureContext(...).getImageData is not a function`

[here](https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/587743) is the code:

```js
PImage hm;
int xstep = 1;
int max_height = 60;
 
void setup() {
  size(600, 400, P3D);
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  textSize(128);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  text("LIGMA", width/2, height/2);
  filter(BLUR, 8);
  hm = get();
}
 
void draw() {
  background(0);
  strokeWeight(2);
  stroke(255);
  float b, z, px, pz;
  translate(width/2, height/2,-20);
  rotateY(map(mouseX,0,width,-PI,PI));
  rotateX(map(mouseY,0,height,-PI,PI));
 
  translate(-width/2, -height/2);
  for (int y = 5; y < height; y+=10) {
    px = -1;
    pz = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x+=xstep) {
      b = brightnes(hm.get(x,y));
      z = map(b, 0, 200, 0, max_height);
      //stroke(color(b));
      line(px, y, pz, x, y, z);
      px = x;
      pz = z;
    }
  }
}
```

Nowhere in my code is this `drawing.$ensureContext(...).getImageData` to be found.  Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: the exception usually tells you the file and the line

Comment: If you open developer tools, you can see the full exception in the console. It looks like an error originating from the processing library itself.

Comment: @Jacob Are there developer tools in processing?

Comment: Processing.js is very old and isn't really recommended for new code anymore. Also note that your code doesn't compile as you've misspelled `brightness`.

Comment: @mckuok it doesn't have it

Comment: I believe that the issue stems from that website assuming only 2D contexts, since `getImageData` is only present if you use `P2D` in your `size(...)` call. Of course, then some of the stuff you're trying to do won't work since it's 3D-specific. So I'm guessing @KevinWorkman is right on the money here.

Comment: @Jodast: I just mean regular browser developer tools (F12 or right-click inspect are ways to get to it)

Comment: @Jacob how could I fix the problem then, my size was `size(600, 400, P3D);`

Comment: My guess is that maybe the site isn't compatible with 3D programs since it's calling `getImageData` on your context.

Comment: @Jacob I tried it on a different website and I tried it using the library in codepen, and neither of them worked.  When I removed the P3D it said `modelView.rotateY is not a function`

Comment: Get something simpler working first. Narrow it down to a single line of code that causes the error. But again, this is probably a result of Processing.js being out of date and not compatible with the latest and greatest browsers and Processing versions.

Comment: @KevinWorkman what do you mean?  I can get simpler processing programs to work.  How much simpler?

Comment: @Jodast I mean, your code has 38 different lines. That makes it hard to isolate the cause. Instead, start with a blank sketch. Get a simple 3D scene working. Now add one function call at a time to figure out what's causing the error. When you figure that out, you can post a [mcve] that contains only that line.

Comment: @KevinWorkman never mind, it was a problem with the site I was using

Comment: @Jodast What was the problem?

Comment: @KevinWorkman The site I was using could only compile JS, and the code was in Java

Comment: @Jodast Are you talking about OpenProcessing? Because it can definitely handle Java syntax in Processing.js. [Here](https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/100757) is an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem may come from this code line and the `P3D` context:

```
filter(BLUR, 8);
```

as `filter()` waits for an image, `PImage` object in processing so it cannot find one.
Remove it and the error will get out.

Look at [this](http://processingjs.org/reference/filter_/) documentation it says:

> Description:  Filters an image as defined by one of the following modes:

`filter()` uses `aImg.loadPixels()` where `aImg` is an image and here is the function `loadPixels` in `ProcessingJS` source code:

```
p.loadPixels = function() {
  p.imageData = drawing.$ensureContext().getImageData(0, 0, p.width, p.height);
};
```

doesn't it reminds you something? :)